# Detect or avoid dead references to temporary on compile time

Tags: c++, static-analysis, c++03, clang-static-analyzer, dangling-pointer

The following minimal-ish program segfaults when compiling with `-O3` and perhaps with `-O2`, but executes fine with `-O0` (with clang 4.0):

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  virtual void me() const { std::cerr << "hi!\n"; }
};

class B {
public:
  B(const A& a_) : a(a_) {}
  virtual void me() const { a.me(); }

private:
  const A& a;
};

class C {
public:
  C(const B& b_) : b(b_) {}
  void me() const { b.me(); }

public:
  const B& b;
};

int main() {
  C c = C(A());
  c.me();
}
```

The reason is that `c.b` is initialized with a reference to a temporary object of class `B` that is constructed from a temporary `A`. After the constructor `c.C()` exits, the temporary `B` is gone but the reference to it remains in `c.b`.

What good practices can I employ to avoid this situation, given that I don't control the implementation of `B` or `A`? Are there static analyzers that are able to detect this condition? (My version of `scan-build` did not find the problem.)

Related: [Detect dangling references to temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340073/detect-dangling-references-to-temporary)

Comment: Well, u now, rvalue references. They bind only to temporaries. I think maybe that can be abstracted up as an lvalue-only-ref-wrapper.

Comment: As a general rule, do not declare member variables of type reference. Use a pointer instead. And if you get a pointer in the constructor the resulting code will be obvious.

Comment: @rodrigo: This sounds interesting. I guess it would also work if I only declare the constructor argument as a pointer, and then initialize the reference? I'd rather not rewrite *all* of the code that uses the reference...

Comment: Try passing `-fsanitize=undefined,address` to the compiler and linker. [ASan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) and [UBSan](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) should notify you at runtime.

Comment: Well, yes, changing just the constructor will make the mistake obvious: if you write `C c = C(&A());` you deserve the crash. I just don't like classes with member references, they make move and copies difficult.

Comment: @rodrigo: Care to write this down as an answer?

Comment: @nwp: Only `-fsanitize-address-use-after-scope` reliably detects the error on my system.

Comment: @krlmlr: I've added an answer explaining what I commented earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally don't like having member variables as references. They cannot be copied or moved, and the user of the class must ensure that the object outlives the reference itself. An exception might be an internal auxiliary class designed to be used as temporary only objects, such as functors.

Replacing the reference with a pointer should be straightforward, and then if you also use a pointer in the constructor:

```
class C {
public:
  C(const A *a_) : a(a_) {}
private:
  const A *a;
};
```

...and so on. If the class is very big and you feel lazy and don't want to change the member, you can just change the constructor:

```
class C {
public:
  C(const A *a_) : a(*a_) {}
private:
  const A &a;
};
```

In order to misuse this class, as the OP says, you'll have to write something like:

```
C c = C(&A());
```

And then the error should be obvious: taking a pointer to a temporary is a very bad idea!

PS: I would add an `explicit` to your constructor, just to avoid it from participating in automatic conversions, which, I think, are part of your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change class `B` or `A`, if that's you mean by adding `explicit`.

Comment: @krimir No, I mean adding a literal `explicit C(const A *a_)` so that the constructor will not be called implicitly as part of type conversions. Some compiler errors may arise, but you will suppress unexpected calls to your constructor

Comment: Personally don't like classes with reference members? Classes with reference members cannot be copied? Huh? Actually they can have a default copy constructor, just like classes with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

I would derive separate classes from `B` and `C` (possibly even using a template class).

These classes would contain a non-reference member which becomes the thing that `a` and `b` refer to.

I'd then implement the necessary copy constructors / assignment operators in these derived classes to prevent dangling references.

(Then I'd have a robust conversation with the author of `B` and `C`).

Comment: This is for an existing code base. What's a good way to find all uses of this anti-pattern?